# How to properly check if a Symfony application is installed?

Tags: symfony, docker, devops

In our Dockerfile's `entrypoint.sh` I need to check (actually the database) to see if there's an application currently installed and if not run a `php app/console` command.

This is my current approach:

```
CHECK=$(php app/console doctrine:query:sql "SELECT * FROM user" -q)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    php app/console vendor:install
fi
```

Which doesn't feel right. What other ways is out there to properly check this?

NOTE That the database is created by a 3rd-party MySql broker service. So I can't check for database existence, 'cause always is true.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Composer hooks, you can check for these files and directories.

Required:

- `app/boostrap.php.cache` or `var/boostrap.php.cache`.
- `app/config/parameters.yml`.
- `vendor/symfony`.
- Check if `app/cache` or `var/cache` has been warmed up.

Optional:

- Check if executing `app/SymfonyRequirements.php` or `var/SymfonyRequirements.php` would return a success - this may fail however for some strict requirements.
- `web/bundles` if there are any assets to install.